# VSTS XCode code coverage

Tags: xcode, azure-devops

I am trying to use slather and xcov to generate a code coverage report for my XCode project hosted in VSTS. I can run the shell scripts on the local machine fine but when I try to run them from a build I receive

```
Slather - no coverage data found

Xcov - command not found
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Do you install Xcov on your build agent machine? If not, try to install it and try again (sudo gem install xcov).

Comment: I can generate the coverage reports fine if I run the commands myself using terminal, the problem is when I add the script to the build and it’s run on the agent. It’s almost like there’s a permissions problem.

Comment: Is the agent installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, my unit / UI tests run fine it just seems to be when running a script. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug to true, then queue build and share the log)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see details for generating the code coverage. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqeMwp-6nL0RcIndEpvyVL_Jf8U regards.

Comment: What's the detail command/script to generate the code coverage report manually? What't the detail code of coverage.sh? The error related to No coverage directory found